# jQuery object never changing except for first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I ran into a problem with an object which I'm trying to modify. The object has a certain amount of keys in the format `key_yyyy-mm-dd`. When certain inputfields lose focus, I trigger a function to modify the object. This function is as follows:

```
function updateHotelBooking()
    {
        $(".no_hotel").each(function(i) {
            var day = $(this).attr('name').match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1];
            hotelBooking["key_" + day] = parseInt($(this).val());
        }); 
    }
```

`.no_hotel` are the textboxes that trigger the function, and they also provide a value which I want to put in my object.

Now, say I put `3` in my first text box, a `console.log` will return the following object:

```
Object
key_2011-08-21: 3
key_2011-08-22: 0
key_2011-08-23: 0
key_2011-08-24: 0
key_2011-08-25: 0
```

However, the next time I put something in the textbox (or another textbox that should trigger the function), it DOES trigger, however the object returned remains the same. So instead of changing the first number to, say, 5, it will just return 3 again.

I have no idea why. My code seems pretty straightforward, and a `console.log` of `day` and `$(this).val()` returns the right values. It's just my object that doesnt get updated.

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

`hotelBooking` is initialized right after `$(document).ready()`:

`var hotelBooking = {};`

The method that calls updateHotelBooking is the following:

```
$(".roomrequest").blur(function()
{
    updateHotelBooking();
});
```

EDIT2: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pBYeD/2/

Comment: How does the function that triggers updateHotelBooking looks like? And where/how is hotelBooking variable initialized?

Comment: How are you setting hotelBooking? also how are you calling your object?

Comment: Can you please post your full code?

Comment: Where are day and your hotel_booking object declared?

Comment: Look at .delegate() . This function will probably solve your problems.

Comment: I updated the question a bit with the triggering function and the init.

Comment: Have you confirmed in the debugger that you're seeing the same problem? Sometimes console.log doesn't update values...

Comment: It would really help if you could post more code.

Comment: Sure, but what parts of the code? I can hardly post the whole file because everyone would see my hacky needs-to-be-refactored stuff ;D The parts I'm showing are the parts that are related to the problem, as far as I can see. The other parts of the code are completely independent.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't see what can cause this problems. How does *$(".roomrequest")* relates to *$(".no_hotel")*? The latter suppose to be textboxes that trigger the function, and now you're showing us a snippet where .roomrequest blur handler calls the updateHotelBooking function. Also, did you try to make simplified example to see if you can reproduce this error ?

Comment: `.roomrequest` and `.no_hotel` are basically the same; however, there are roomrequest textboxes without the no_hotel class. i was just trying to split my calculations up per class, if that makes sense. like, for the boxes with `no_hotel`, i need to do a different calculation than the boxes without. i'll try to make a simplified example in a moment, as soon as i get some free time >.<

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle which shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/pBYeD/2/

Comment: Your JSFiddle works fine for me in chrome.

Comment: You're fiddle is working just fine for me (firefox, linux 64 bits).

Comment: That makes me a sad panda. It doesn't work for me in either safari or chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has to do with something with the console rather than your code, if you change the logging code to this, you will see that you have the correct values:

```
    function updateHotelBooking()
    {
        $(".no_hotel").each(function(i) {
            var day = $(this).attr('name').match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1];
            hotelBooking["key_" + day] = parseInt($(this).val());     
            **logObject(hotelBooking);**      
        });     
    }  


function logObject(hotelBooking){
        for(var i in hotelBooking){
            console.log(i+": "+hotelBooking[i]);
        }
        console.log("------");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that function for a while while developing this part.

Comment: LOL - that was the problem?? I assume @cabaret uses chrome - it's console has some weird-ass way of displaying objects. That's not the case in Firefox + Firebug

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the problem does not come from the debugger output?

As far as i can see in my chrome output, if i let the fiddle as is, the object doesn't appear to change in the console (just the number on the left takes a +3). However if I add something like `console.log(hotelBooking["key_" + day]);` just before or after, it's shown as changing.

Comment: i also think this is the case

Comment: This probably is the case yeah, it seems to work fine in Firefox.. should've tested that earlier I guess. I'll be developing in FF for a while. Thanks!

Comment: I think FF is always better to develop, firebug is (imho) a way better debugger than the others.